# Why not inject IServiceProvider instead of each individual dependency?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am wondering why one wouldn't explicitly use the IServiceProvider to resolve dependencies over injecting each dependency individually. In other words, why use this approach:

```
public class A 
{
    private B _b;
    private C _c;
    private D _d;
    private E _e;

    public A(B b, C c, D d, E e)
    {
        _b = b;
        _c = c;
        _d = d;
        _e = e;
    }
}
```

and not this:

```
public class A 
{
    private B _b;
    private C _c;
    private D _d;
    private E _e;

    public A(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        _b = (b) sp.GetService(typeof(b));
        _c = (c) sp.GetService(typeof(c));
        _d = (d) sp.GetService(typeof(d));
        _e = (e) sp.GetService(typeof(e));
    }
}
```

*Note that I may not call `GetService` for **all** of the types, some of the types may be effectively optional (i.e. sometimes used, sometimes not used).*

The advantage of the second approach being that we don't need to make a change in every place where we are calling the constructor of A if there is a change in the dependencies of A, and we don't need to have all of the dependencies already available wherever we are calling the constructor.

MS seems to recommend against this in the following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#recommendations 
They mention to avoid using the service locator pattern instead of DI, but aren't we still using DI here? Is the same thing not happening in the background anyway?

Comment: *... wherever we are calling the constructor ...* ... then why you need DI?

Comment: With the second approach, you are injecting whole application dependencies where ever you are intending to use them regardless of which dependencies you actually need. This will increase the object creation time.

Comment: If I read your code and you're injecting `IServiceProvider` instead of just the services you need, I'd assume that you have a good reason for that like resolving services you don't know the type yet or something like that. However, even in that scenario there would be better ways to do that, so it will just end up being confusing imo. Btw with DI you should almost never be calling a constructor especially for a service.

Comment: `but aren't we still using DI here?` The class has not made clear to its consumers what dependencies it has (with your proposal). You are effectively using SL. This makes, among other things, unit testing harder (try and write a unit test for the two different approaches and you'll soon see why the first is preferred).

Comment: @Selvin Without getting too specific, we are instantiating classes in our MVC controllers that have the same (kind of) dependencies as our controllers but not the very same ones every time. We don't want to have to add the dependencies of those classes to the dependencies of our controllers, because this would create overhead and mean we would need to change them in 2 (or more) places every time there is a change.

Comment: `we don't need to make a change in every place where we are calling the constructor of A if there is a change in the dependencies of A` You shouldn't be using `A` anywhere. You should be using `IA` instead, and `A` should **implement** `IA` (and you register `A` with the container). If you do so, then any DI of A will work - you won't need to "change in every place". It will "just work".

Comment: @Muhammad Hannan thanks, that makes sense

Comment: `we are instantiating classes in our MVC controllers that have the same (kind of) dependencies as our controllers` Have you registered them as scoped dependencies? If so, this should "just work".

Comment: I'd strongly recommend reading https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/ .

Comment: @mjwills We could register A as a service and inject it in the controllers that may have to instantiate it. However, at compile time we don't know which (Ab, Ac, Ad, etc) of these services we would need to instantiate. This would mean we have to add 10+ dependencies to our controllers (only one of which we would use per request), instead of just the one (IServiceProvider) which we would then pass along. This is fine, I guess, but not pretty either.

Comment: Ah, so you want only a **subset** of the dependencies. In that case, inject `Lazy<A>` / `Func<A>` instead of `A` into the constructor. The inbuilt container may not support this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but more fully featured ones like Autofac will. Using `Lazy` or `Func` is great because it **expresses your intent**. Your class makes clear what dependencies it has. This makes, for example, unit testing easier.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't know about Lazy<T>. Would still need to inject Lazy<A>, Lazy<F>, Lazy<G> etc instead of just the IServiceProvider but this does make it more bearable. Thanks

Comment: Try my idea and yours. Now try and write a unit test for both of them. Honestly, that is where you'll realise how painful SL is.

Comment: How do you manage the lifetime of your dependencies (scoped, transient, and singleton) in your proposed solution?

Comment: @MartBroekkamp If you have 10+ dependencies in a single controller - that's a code smell, telling your that your controller is doing too much. I'd split that into smaller controllers. Or aggregate dependencies behind facades. Also creating instances of services should be cheap and easy, i.e. constructors should not do anything other than assign dependencies.

Comment: @mjwills OP, as far as I know the service locator pattern has nothing intrinsic for dealing with lifetime.  As you've already pointed out, it'll be a pain.

Comment: @Matthew The lifetime of the services in this case is transient

Comment: @mjwills Point taken, I tried writing unit tests for the IServiceProvider way and quickly realized how much of a pain that would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several reasons. 
When you use dependency injection, you are giving the DI container responsibility for preparing your dependencies for you. The classes shouldn't care about how your dependencies are created. If you switch to a different DI library you would have to change constructors in all of your classes.

Another small concern is that you would have to create a mock for your service container in every unit test which is not a huge issue but definitely something that could be annoying.

Lastly your code will become very strange when you have to pass dependencies to nested classes, not to mention any time you want to have inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the Service Locator Pattern -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern

It has some advantages and disadvantages (described in the article), however it is widely viewed as an anti-pattern.

---

You state that you are calling constructors yourself (as in `new SomeService(...)` I'm guessing), which is a sign of not using DI (or only partially).

Comment: Partially, I suppose. We are using DI without IServiceProvider in our controllers.

I figured even if we're injecting IServiceProvider and getting our services from there, we're still using DI because we don't need to pass the dependencies along everywhere, only the IServiceProvider which, through the DI framework, can get us our dependencies. My assumption was that something similar to this happens in the background, but I guess it's true that putting all of your dependencies in the constructor more clearly expresses intent to the framework.