# Get dependency when needed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Is there any way to get/fetch dependencies only when it is needed?

```
public class DependentClass
{
    public DependentClass(IMandatoryDependency mandatoryDependency, IDependency1 dependency1, IDependency2 dependency2, IDependency3 dependency3)
    {
        // Assigned to class level property
    }

    public void MethodsOne()
    {
        mandatoryDependency.CallMandatoryMethod();
        dependency1.CallDependecy1Method();
    }

    public void MethodsTwo()
    {
        mandatoryDependency.CallMandatoryMethod();
        dependency2.CallDependecy2Method();
    }

    public void MethodsThree()
    {
        mandatoryDependency.CallMandatoryMethod();
        dependency3.CallDependecy3Method();
    }
}
```

From the above snippet, I would like to get the dependency for individual methods when I am inside the methods itself. Something like this:

```
public class DependentClass
{
    public DependentClass(IMandatoryDependency mandatoryDependency)
    {
        // Assigned to class level property
    }

    public void MethodsOne()
    {
        mandatoryDependency.CallMandatoryMethod();
        DIContainer.GetDependency<IDependency1>().CallDependecy1Method();
    }

    public void MethodsTwo()
    {
        mandatoryDependency.CallMandatoryMethod();
        DIContainer.GetDependency<IDependency2>().CallDependecy2Method();
    }

    public void MethodsOne()
    {
        mandatoryDependency.CallMandatoryMethod();
        DIContainer.GetDependency<IDependency3>().CallDependecy3Method();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can resolve from the DI container in the method yes, most DI frameworks allow you to inject the container itself as a dependency, however, most of the time there's a better pattern you can use for stuff like this, what's the reason for wanting the dependency injected at the point of usage? It sounds like you might benefit from injecting a factory instead or using some of the more complex resolution features. What DI container are you using also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in asp.net core we can inject `IServiceProvider` in controller and resolve dependencies ourselves on run-time like:

```
private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
private IMandatoryDependency _mandatoryDependency;
public DependentClass(IMandatoryDependency mandatoryDependency,
                      IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    _mandatoryDependency = mandatoryDependency;
}
```

and in method we can request the provider to give the instance of a particular dependency like :

```
public void MethodsOne()
{
    mandatoryDependency.CallMandatoryMethod();
    _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IDependency1)).CallDependecy1Method();
}
```

But it is not considered a good idea to inject `IServiceProvider` see :

[Why not inject IServiceProvider instead of each individual dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674730/why-not-inject-iserviceprovider-instead-of-each-individual-dependency)

You can look in more details about the dependency injection service particularly in asp.net core at following :

https://andrewlock.net/new-in-asp-net-core-3-service-provider-validation/

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/17ee0ba2-99bb-47f0-ab18-f4fc32f476f8.aspx

Also read about best practices for Dependency Injection in asp.net core:

https://medium.com/volosoft/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-best-practices-tips-tricks-c6e9c67f9d96

Comment: @CodeCaster yes there are obvious drawback of moving to service locator as we are ourselves driving the dependency resolution instead of having that done by DI container itself for us, but it's one of the ways we can

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I appreciate your effort but this solution is not convincing enough.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using an IOC container ,You can inject an instance of the container it self in the constructor and then used this instance to resolve your services bad it's not a good practice , you might be looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548487/ioc-container-inject-container)

Another good option would be making the optional dependencies a Lazy objects , by simply using the Lazy class , so you code will be `Lazy<IDependency1>`

using the lazy pattern ensure that the objects are not instantiated unless you actually want to access them , you can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It is a good solution but I am finding more convincing answer. @MostafaElite

Answer (score 1):

You need to register services as Lazily in `StartUp.cs`.

```
services.AddTransient<IDependecy1, Dependecy1>();
services.AddTransient(serviceProvider => new Lazy<IDependecy1>(() => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDependecy1>()));
```

Then in your `Controller` use dependency as [Lazy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.8)

```
public class DependentClass
{
    private readonly Lazy<IDependency1> _dependency1;
    public DependentClass(IMandatoryDependency mandatoryDependency, Lazy<IDependency1> dependency1)
    {
        // Assigned to class level property
        _dependency1 = dependency1;
    }

    public void MethodsOne()
    {
        mandatoryDependency.CallMandatoryMethod();
        _dependency1.Value.CallDependecy1Method();
    }
}
```

If you are using IDependency1 just in one method, so you can resolve the dependency using [FromServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromservicesattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in **.NET core** instead of injecting dependency in constructor.

```
public void MethodsOne([FromServices] IDependency1 dependency1)
    {
        mandatoryDependency.CallMandatoryMethod();
        dependency1.CallDependecy1Method();
    }
```

Comment: `FromServices` solution looks good. I will definitely try this and get back you on this. @Voodoo

Comment: Yes, you can use it when you need the service for one time only.

Comment: It seems like `FromServices` is suppose to be used in only controller not in other places otherwise we need to pass the dependency as a parameter. Correct me If I am wrong. @Voodoo

Comment: No, you can use it in method without passing it, just register the service in `Startup.cs` and use it without passing explicitly.